# How to impelment iPhone like Drag to Scroll Scrollviewer in WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have a scrollviewer which contains number of buttons and forms. Now I want this application to scroll like in iPhone in touchscreen computers.

I have been trying to modify this tutorial:

[Drag scrollable ListView](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29886/DraggableListView-Adding-drag-to-scroll-functional&ei=8tVIT9eoK4TrrQefx_HHDw&usg=AFQjCNGZ-ttehT1TlN-zoYHW8DgLQK4ehw&sig2=f7JSePQ0UaZVO9_rDochUg)

It implements double click to select the list item. However, I rather wanted to use single click so I changed the following code like this:

```
// initial source code values
// this registers the double click
isMouseDoubleClick = (e.ClickCount>1);
```

I changed it to..

```
// Get initial position of the mouse.
Point initialPos = e.GetPosition(this);
// initialize the isMouseDoubleClick;
isMouseDoubleClick  = false
//if the button is pressed and hold (not released yet)..
if (e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed) {

    // if the hold position is same
    if (e.GetPosition(this) == initialPose) {
        
        //if mouse released
         if (e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Released) {
              // set isMouseDoubleClick  true;
               isMouseDoubleClick = true;
         }
    }
}
```

But it does not seems to work.

How does they made it work in iPhone.

The item does not gets selected when touched for a while and also while dragged but it gets selected in a single tap.

How can I make it happen similar in WPF application? A click will select the list item. Click and Hold will not select the list item.